# If the OS on my micro-sd card is infected with malware, would I need to scrub infected sd-card first, or, just dd a clean OS to the infected sd-card?

Tags: linux, malware

**PURPOSE**: Create new, malware-free OS (3GB) on an (malware) infected micro-sd card (16GB).

**HOW**? Rewriting the OS to the infected sd-card ***FROM*** a clean, (2nd) sd-card, using 'dd' command: (ie: "sudo dd if=/dev/sdx bs=16M of=/dev/sdy")

If my debian10 OS (located on my micro-sd), was infected with malware, would I need to *scrub* the "infected sd-card" first, before writing a new, clean OS to it? Or, could I just use the "dd" command and write a clean OS to that "infected" sd-card, thereby not wasting the time to initially clean it, so long as it would be truly free of the malware?

Comment: @moab It may be a hypothetical question, but there is nothing broad about it. It is a good question with a narrow scope and a well-defined good answer (which grawity already provided). And as far as I know there is no rule mandating closing hypothetical questions just for being hypothetical. Hypothetical questions can be too broad. They often are, but not in this case and I see no reason to close it.

Comment: @Tonny Thanks. In this case, it would be simple to change it to a non-hypothetical by simply saying that my OS "IS" infected...do I need to do A or B to create a clean one.

Comment: @Moab Overall, true, but in this case, there is no hardware firmware on a small sd-card, so for this example, it probably wouldn't fit. Thanks. As a sidenote, I have been told that you can get rid of the malware in the firmware by cold flashing it and the bios, and that for someone who knows how to do it, it is not that difficult to do. However, finding someone who knows how to do it, and has the tools for it, is a completely different story!

Comment: @topencrypt It would be that simple. I understand moab’s reasoning because at times we get a lot of really bad “what if” questions. But this just isn’t one of those. By the way: it is customary to wait at least a day before accepting an answer. This gives others a chance and incentive to provide alternative answers or suggest improvements to the existing answer(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dd` makes a byte-identical copy. If you write a 16 GiB image to the card, then the first 16 GiB of the card are *completely* overwritten with the card's contents.

If the card is larger than the image, then the remaining data beyond the image's size will not be touched at all, and the OS could still read all the old data from there if it wanted to.

However, the OS will not actually *use* that area, since the image's partition table doesn't actually extend any partitions that far (obviously), and the image's filesystem doesn't know anything about that area. Even if you manually extended the partitions later, the filesystem would just consider that area to be empty – it won't rediscover actual files that might have been there previously.

So in both cases, it is safe to just write the new image.

---

(A given location can only store one value. Once old data has been overwritten *even once*, there's no command for the SD card to undo it – the OS cannot re-discover the old data by "reading harder" or anything like that.

Though with flash-based memory, it might show up instead of the new data if something has gone very wrong with the card's wear-leveling system, but more likely the card will just refuse to accept any writes at all if that happens)

Comment: at grawity: Thanks. "If the card is larger than the image, then the remaining data beyond the image's size will not be touched at all, and the OS could still read all the old data from there if it wanted to." When I dd the OS, which is a working OS, not an image, output states that 15GB were copied over to the infected sd-card. If there were anything outside the OS on the card, wouldn't it get over-written with zeros, for ie, since the clean/new sd has nothing but the OS?

Comment: at grawity: ...I know you said, basically, hypothetically, that the OS could read the old data, but that realistically, it won't. Based on what you have stated, the answer to my question in the comment would be no. But the reason I am asking is b/c of the output showing that 15GB, of a 16GB card, were "copied". Thanks.